# Incremental Migration

Tags: migration

I'm currently in the process of migrating/moving a customer's SharePoint 2013 with ShareGate. The problem is when that I need to do the migration in two step, one full and one incremental. Does anybody have a suggestion on how to handle files that have been deleted in the source environment between the two migrations?

Comment: I disagree that the question is off-topic since the problem I had has to do with migration in general not with the tool.

Comment: In case of out-of-the-box migration when you would detach/attach a database, that problem wouldn't even exist. So it's the tool specific issue you are having.

Answer (score 0):

we also faced same scenario while migrating using ShareGate, to overcome this we created a console application to generate the report which has details of items present in the destination but not is source. After cross checking report we run another console to read this report and delete files in destination. this will work until the destination server is not live (not started to use), after its live if you follow this process newly added file or items will get deleted.

Comment: Thank you for the replay. I was thinking in the same direction, I guess it's the only way to go.

Comment: :-) yes, we ended up same thing